# Do I need to make 3 item tables to store item list for Purchase Order, Delivery Challan & Purchase Returns in an inventory system?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, inventory

The process: I issue a PURCHASE ORDER to Supplier who delivers a part of the items specified. I accept some items and return the defective items. Do I need to create 3 item tables for the 3 documents?

Format:

```
Sr.no = 001
Product ID= ITEM_01
Product Name= ITEM1
QTY = 10
PRICE = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first pass, and depending on your reporting needs:

**Table1: PO log**
ID
Purchase order number
Supplier ID
Product ID
Qty
Price per item
Date
Action type (received, returned)

**Table2: Supplier info**
Supplier ID
Supplier Name
Other Supplier info

**Table3: Product info**
Product ID
Product Name
Other product info